# Put List reference vs copy to Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I have single List. I populate him and then put him into map. Then I clear the list, populate him again, and put him into same map under different key. Ans so on in a loop.

```
Map<String, List<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyClass(id_1));
map.put("key_1", list);
list.clear();
list.add(new MyClass(id_2));
map.put("key_2", list);
//map is = {key_1:id_2, key_2:id_2}
//Why map is NOT = {key_1:id_1, key_2:id_2}
```

Why it seems that the map get reference to the list instead of new copy of the list?

Comment: You have single list. Just like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same reference of the list to the Map: "key_1" and "key_2" both point to the same `List` object. What you need to do is create a second list based from the first:

```
Map<String, List<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyClass(id_1));
map.put("key_1", list);
list.clear();
list.add(new MyClass(id_2));
map.put("key_2", new ArrayList<>(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just how Java works. What how are putting into the map is a reference to the list. If you want to copy the list you need to do it explicitly.

```
List<MyClass> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do map.put("key_2", list), you're putting a reference to the list object.
You have to instantiate another list object.